# Picture is not switching with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my code set so when you click the picture switches, and then a menu pops up. (I haven't finished the menu yet). But when I click on the picture, it is not changing. Can you tell me how to fix my code thanks.
I can't get jsfiddle to work so here is my website http://spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehomemenu.html

And the troubling code is:

```
function showMore() {
    if (more.style.display != "none") {
        more.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        more.style.display = "block";
    }
}

imgs = Array("more.png", "less.png");
var x = 0;

function change() {
    document.getElementById("bob").src = imgs[++x];

    if (x == 1) {
        x = -1;
    }
}
if (!imgs[x + 1]) {
    x = -1;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae5wa/)**

(yes I have all of the appropriate body and html tags, I just thought it wasn't needed to demonstrate my problem) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't have an ID called bob. So when you try to call:

```
document.getElementById("bob") ...
```

This is null.

You need to set the image you want to change to have an id called bob (Why you've called it bob though?)

Comment: In your site, bottomCorner is a DIV, not an IMG, so you can't change it's src. Give the IMG tag an ID and use that to change the src.

Comment: Now it works to a degree, it just doesn't go back to the way it should after you click it a second time..

Comment: I also changed the onmousedown to onclick. Don't know if that is a difference

Comment: I fixed it. I put if x==1 x=-1. Stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

As Lee said, you missed giving an ID to the img. Also, you closed your change() function a little early, so it would never get to the second if.

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("bob").src = imgs[++x];

    if (x == 1) {
        x = -1;
    }
//} Moved from here
if (!imgs[x + 1]) {
    x = -1;
}
}
```

working here: [edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae5wa/1/)